# How to call program from web?

Tags: java, windows, macos

How to call program from web. Just like yahoo messenger

```
ymsgr:sendIM?myyahooid
```

I need solution to call a J2SE application from web for both Windows and Mac

Comment: From web, you mean web browser?

Comment: If you mean browser then you can use applet for this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Those are called URL handlers.

Here is how to do it for windows.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa767914(v=vs.85).aspx

Answer (score 2):

You can think about Java Web Start it will make your j2se application as web based so from web u can call your java application...
check the link https://stackoverflow.com/tags/java-web-start/info